# C - write 4 bytes, but then increment pointer by only 3

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to write 4 bytes, but then increment pointer by only 3 bytes, and write another 4 bytes (overwriting the last byte), but everything ive tried inc's the ptr by 1 or 4, and I have a feeling even if I jinxed it it probably wouldn't be the best method. How to specifically increment by 3, and what is the recommended approach? It seems that using a (char *) cast might be the way to go?

```
 uint32_t value = 0x00112233;
 uint32_t *ptr = (buffertowrite);
 *ptr = value;  // write 4 bytes
 ptr += 3;      // but only move forward 3 bytes
 *ptr = value;  // write next 4 bytes (overwriting the last byte)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Even ıf you could, alignment would be another issue. Prepare 4 numbers which are 4 bytes as their first bytes are taken, Write it. Write in 4 byte chunks. Or byte by byte.

Comment: If you are interested in bytes, then `ptr` should be of type `unsigned char *`.   When the type is `uint32_t`, incrementing by 3 makes the value 3 * sizeof(uint32_t) larger.

Comment: Perhaps I should explain it another way -- I'm trying to do in C what would be the following in x86:
`code
    mov [eax], 0x00112233 ...
     add eax, 3 ...
     mov [eax], 0x00112233 ...
     add eax, 3 ...
     ....`

Comment: @KerryDaniels: that should go into the question.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) is a programming language, so is a *specification* (it is *not* a software). Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft.

> How to specifically increment by 3, and what is the recommended approach? It seems that using a (char *) cast might be the way to go?

That is very probably some [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (in general). On some computers, it might "work" (but very slowly, because you make an unaligned access, read about [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)). You could try;

```
ptr = (uint32_t*)((char*)ptr + 3);
```

But you should **avoid coding like that** (it is some ugly non-[portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) code, with bad smell). On many [computer architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) or [instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), you are likely to get a [bus error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) or a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). On some computers where that is not crashing, it might be a [non-atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) operation (you might not be sure of what would happen if that code was [scheduled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) so got a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) or some [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) inside). Read also about [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) & [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing).

So I recommend not coding like that, even if it happens to apparently work (a future [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) compiler might do things differently) on your machine. If you need to code such bad things, be sure to at least add a big fat warning in some comment. Perhaps use [`volatile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_%28computer_programming%29) (or some [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)). Be sure to check the emitted assembler code (e.g. with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S`).

<sup>(a less ugly solution might be to copy byte by byte)</sup>

Take time to read Lattner's blog on [*What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html); you really need to read that *carefully*.

<sup>(not getting any warnings, and getting some *apparently* working code, is the worst kind of undefined behavior; you should be [*very scared*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108), and you are not scared enough!)</sup>

Since you are thinking from some piece of code in assembler, you might consider using an `asm` statement. Read [*Using Assembly Language with C*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html).

Comment: But where is the fun in that ;)

Comment: I agree that too much casting could easily lead to pointer aliasing and thereby undefined behavior. Good answer as always Basile.

Comment: Basile thankyou! I tried a lot of variations in that ballpark but no luck, but with your help i'm not even getting any warnings so it's looking good! Thanks again

Comment: No it is not looking good. It is smelling very bad. You are not ashamed enough.

Comment: Geez, Basile I don't think he's writing the landing system for an aeroplane. Mucking around like this how you learn. And if he/she wants to implement an aligned version of malloc this is much needed understanding.

Comment: But in 6 months when he has upgraded his compiler the behavior is likely to be different

Comment: But not in the way it accesses the individual bytes. Look it is crazy what they're doing but I think it is more of learning exercise. Building with optimisation is often fraught with dangers even if you follow the C standard. The compiler can do some crazy things if you don't tell it exactly where and what needs to be optimised.

Comment: It's perfectly valid (it seems?) in x86 to do (for example) "mov [eax], cl" then "inc eax" to move ptr+1 then "mov [eax], cl" etc to repeatedly fill a buffer one byte at a time - obviously 3 out of 4 of these single byte writes will not be aligned, but the CPU allows it, so I'm confused why "(char *)ptr+3" in C is so "bad"?   cdcdcd yes I'm just trying to learn because i find this very interesting and if i think it's important to know how to (and not) do fundamental things like memory i/o, and making mistakes and learning why they're 'bad' etc is a healthy part of the process!

Comment: But C is not x86. It provides an abstraction layer, and the compiler takes advantage of that by doing optimization.

Answer (score -1):

1. If it's **bytes** you're talking about, then you should work with bytes, or something of `uint8_t` type instead of `uint32_t`.
2. Looking at your types I'd say this

   ```
   uint32_t *ptr = (buffertowrite);
   ptr += 3;      // but only move forward 3 bytes
   ```

   is pretty wrong. Pointer arithmetics will move the pointer `3*sizeof(uint32_t)` bytes forward.